# Same power in the circuit comparison

Tags: voltage, power, current, circuit-design, resistance

I have 2 circuits with the same power (900W), could anyone please explain the big different between these two? Circuit one has 30V, 1 Ohm, 30A and 900W of power. Circuit 2 100V, 11 ohms, 9,09A, 900-909W. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I would like to rephrase my question (I don't know how to upload the ckt drawing). This is just one heater connected to a voltage source with the same power output. Ckt 1: 30V, 1 ohm, 30A, 900W. ckt2: 100V, 11.11 ohms, 9A, 900W. Ckt 1 has lower voltage but higher current. Ckt 2 has higher voltage but lower current. Which circuit is more likely to cause failure to the heater. Advantages vs disadvantages between 2 circuits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take two circuits equivalent to yours, building the resistive loads from smaller components. One is as you describe, 30 V into 1 Ω, the other is similar, 90 V into 9 Ω instead of your 100 V into 11 Ω, and compare them.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f413vC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, each component resistor has 30 V across it, 10 A through it, and is dissipating 300 W. In the left hand circuit, they are connected in parallel, and you have a low impedance supply (low voltage high current). In the right hand circuit, they are in series, and the supply is higher impedance (high voltage low current). The first circuit will need much thicker cables to connect to it than the second.

This general idea of the same power, but different impedance, can be found cropping up everywhere we want to shift power over a distance. If you have several solar panels on your roof for instance, a series connection will mean you can use lighter gauge wire to conduct the power down to your inverters.

You can raise voltage and reduce current until the costs of insulating the high voltage becomes prohibitive in your particular application. In plastic insulated cable, anything up to 300 V or so is practically free, as if the insulation is physically strong enough to survive handling, it's good for a few hundred volts. Above that, you need to work on the insulation, the extreme being the 100 kV and higher on overhead high voltage lines, where the huge distances provide the incentive for working with very high voltages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that higher voltage would require better insulation. Sorry I would like to rephrase my question (I don't know how to upload the ckt drawing). This is just one heater connected to a voltage source with the same power output. Ckt 1: 30V, 1 ohm, 30A, 900W. ckt2: 100V, 11.11 ohms, 9A, 900W. Ckt 1 has lower voltage but higher current. Ckt 2 has higher voltage but lower current. Which circuit is more likely to cause failure to the heater. Advantages vs disadvantages between 2 circuits.

Comment: @YbxNop At those low voltages, no difference in safety with respect to voltage. If one resistor fails open (likely), the parallel circuit will keep heating at reduced output, whereas the series circuit will stop entirely. If one fails short (unlikely, maybe), the parallel circuit will blow the fuse (fails safe) whereas the series circuit will continue heating at much higher power (unsafe). Looks like the parallel circuit wins on both.